# Running foreach loop with ttest and sdtest in Stata

Tags: stata

I need to run `ttest` in Stata on many variables (a, b, c, d) in a `foreach` loop

I try:

```
foreach var in varlist 'a-d'{
ttest 'var', by(c)
}
```

and

```
foreach var of varlist `a-d'{
ttest `a-d', by(c)
}
```

But these code patterns work well only with other tests, but not `ttest` and `sdtest`.

What is my mistake?

Comment: Already answered in detail on Statalist, before this was even posted here. I suggest that people don't waste their time answering this. (http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-01/msg00199.html)

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Finally, I could compile the code (after reading <help foreach>): foreach var of varlist aaa-ccc t* {
               anova 'var'
        }  (first quote is under ~ on keyboards)  I don`t know why, but ttest and sdtest could not run. In the previously described loop I had run corr and summarize commands.

Comment: The left quote ` can be in quite different places in keyboards distributed in different countries.

Comment: I could run the following codes: foreach x in distance var62 var122 var182 var242 var302 var362 var403 var463 var503 var563 var623 var683 var722 var782 var842 var902 var962 var1022 var1082 {
 ttest `x' = distance
}
 quotes are missing 
foreach x in distance var62 var122 var182 var242 var302 var362 var403 var463 var503 var563 var623 var683 var722 var782 var842 var902 var962 var1022 var1082 {
 oneway `x' distance
}

foreach x in var62 var122 var182 var242 var302 var362 var403 var463 var503 var563 var623 var683 var722 var782 var842 var902 var962 var1022 var1082{
  median `x', by (distance)
 }

Answer (score 0):

Here's is a sample that works for a two group mean t test

```
foreach v of var var2-var6 {
ttest `var', by(var1)
}
```

Comment: Nick's comment about the ` is also very imporant.  It looks like you have two 'not `'